# How to solve this iterations and read method errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-handling

```
for text in Horizontal_File:
    if text.find("THETA    PHI")!=-1:
    valueoftext = Horizontal_File.readline()
    SplitValue=valueoftext.split()
    phi_List_Horizontal.append(SplitValue[1])
    RCS_List_Horizontal.append(SplitValue[6])
```

The Error it throws me is "ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data"

Comment: do format your code with the right indentation

Comment: Yeah Its a type error!
Any help with the code ?

Comment: Please show the full exception, not a description of it. (And it can't possibly be both a `ValueError` and `TypeError` at the same time.)

Comment: Your if block is still not indented right.

Answer (score 3):

```
for text in Horizontal_File:
```

always gets next line of file with every iteration of loop.

And readline() also gets next line in (this case the same) file for every call.

1. So text will have line #1 of file
2. if you find the thing you search in text, valueoftext will take the line #2 of file
3. And the next call of loop will get line #3 and the start of loop will never see line #2

Python thinks it is an error, because usually you want for loop to get all lines and what you wrote is usually an error.

If this is really not the case, you shall have to make a workaround, so that python understands you really mean it. In Python 2 you can use valueoftext=Horizontal_File.next() and in Python 3 valueoftext=next(Horizontal_File). However, you should make sure, you are not reaching past end of file while trying to get next line, else you will receive StopIteration exception.

Comment: `for text in Horizonal_File.readline():` reads the first line and iterates over the characters in it. `for text in Horizontal_File:` iterates over the file one line at a time. They're not at all the same thing.

Comment: @abarnert thank you, you are,of course, right; dunno what came over me; reworded.

Comment: Good explanation. It might also be worth explaining that he probably either wants to just use `text`, or call `next(Horizontal_File)` instead of `Horizontal_File.readline()`, depending on what he's trying to do.